# Are there line continuation character for string in Terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-provider-azure

I am writing some long SQL queries in a Terraform file, the query would be like:

```
"CREATE TABLE example_${var.name} (id string, name string..........................................)"
```

To make the query readable, I hope the query would be the format like the following, and cross multiple lines

```
CREATE TABLE example_$(var.name) (
                                   id string, 
                                   name string,
 ................................
)
```

Is there a line continuation character for a long single line string to be written as multiple lines. Just like we could use backslash `\` in Python for long string?

I have tried use heredoc, but it does not work when running the query. Thanks

Comment: Heredoc works fine for this sort of thing. If it "doesn't work when running the query" then include details of exactly what you are trying, and what error or issue you encounter, in your question.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your goal is to have a long SQL query defined in Terraform, but across multiple lines so you don't need to horizontal scroll to infinity and beyond.

In my team we use heredoc to achieve this although you said it's not possible in your case.

Another idea my team use when heredoc isn't possible is to join an array of strings.

E.g.

```
locals {
  sql = join(",", [
    "id string",
    "name string",
    "address string",
    "renter string",
    "profession string"
  ])
}
```

Results in

```
> local.sql
id string,name string,address string,renter string,profession string
```

I hope I've understood your question correctly but if not please let me know.

PS: There's an [open issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/hcl/issues/211) for multiline strings in Terraform

Answer (score 1):

To make a multi-line strings in Terraform using the [heredoc](https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/strings) string syntax.

```
locals {
  sql = <<EOT
CREATE TABLE example_$(var.name) (
                                   id string, 
                                   name string,
 ................................
)
EOT
}
```

Comment: Agreed, heredoc is preferred however I noticed in the code block OP shared mentions `I have tried use heredoc, but it does not work when running the query. Thanks` so I assumed it was not possible in their situation